# What exact blob containers do I need to purge during a WebJob SDK log cleanup process?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

** **Problem Background** **

As we know, Azure WebJob SDK, has no way of defining a retention policy for logs. That means the execution or dashboard Blob storage can grow and impose problems including slowing down or crash the kudu Dashboard – which could compromise the stability of the other apps in the App Service plan.

The problem stated here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/560

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1050

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/107

My web job functions are extensively logging and they are running more than 100,000 times a day. That means I have a huge amount of log files piled up in my storage.

** **The Workaround approach that I am planning:** **

I am planning to add a time trigger Functions to my WebJob code that purges log entries older than 30 days.

We have the following blob containers created or used by the WebJobs SDK:

1.**Storage Connection: AzureWebJobsDashboard**

```
 1.1. azure-webjobs-dashboard
 1.2. azure-jobs-host-archive
 1.3. Duplicates with AzureWebJobsStorage
      1.3.1 azure-jobs-host-output
      1.3.2 azure-webjobs-host
```

2.**Storage AzureWebJobsStorage**

```
 2.1. azure-jobs-host-output
 2.2. azure-webjobs-host
    2.2.1 Heartbeats 
    2.2.2 Ids
    2.2.3 Output-logs
```

I am thinking to create a process that deletes every file older than 30 days from above containers. But I am concern that some of the blobs might be required by the running WebJobs.

** **Question** **

Which of the above blob containers do I need to purge, to prevent blob file pile-up problem without interfering running WebJobs ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, AzureWebJobsDashboard connection string account is used to store logs from the WebJobs Dashboard. This connection string is optional.

It will generate two container 'azure-webjobs-dashboard'and 'azure-jobs-host-archive'.

Azure-webjobs-dashboard: WebJob dashboard to store host and execution endpoint (function) details

Azure-jobs-host-archive: This is used as an archive for execution logs.

So both of these containers could be deleted without interfering running WebJobs.

azure-jobs-host-output is the key for troubleshooting web jobs. This container hosts logs created by the WebJob runtime during initialization and termination of every execution. If you don't want this log , you could delete it.

Azure-webjobs-host container in-turn hosts three directories:

Heartbeats – Containing 0 byte blogs for every heartbeat check performed on the service. If you don't want it, you could delete the old file.

Ids – Containing the directory with a single blog holding a unique identifier for this service.I don't suggest you delete this container's file.

Output-logs – Hosts the output of the explicit logs for each run. Explicit logs being logs introduced by WebJob developers within the execution code. You could delete the old log.

Answer (score 1):

We've just implemented Storeage Lifecycle Management and are testing this:

```
{
    "version": "0.5",
    "rules": [
        {
            "name": "DeleteOldLogs",
            "type": "Lifecycle",
            "definition": {
                "actions": {
                    "baseBlob": {
                        "delete": {
                            "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 30
                        }
                    }
                },
                "filters": {
                    "blobTypes": [
                        "blockBlob"
                    ],
                    "prefixMatch": [
                        "azure-webjobs-host/output-logs",
                        "azure-webjobs-dashboard/functions/recent",
                        "azure-webjobs-dashboard/functions/instances",
                        "azure-jobs-host-output",
                        "azure-jobs-host-archive"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Done testing it? Can you provide an update on whether this worked effectively? Any tweaks need to be made? Thanks!

Comment: Lifecycle management seems like the way to go. Nice one, @Lee Tracey.

Comment: In the end we decided to go back to a V1 storage account for our infrastructure assets, like this. The cost is around 10x cheaper than the v2 storage account(!), but comes with no lifecycle mgmt.